# Converting an image to text

Tags: qt, text, qimage, qstring, qpixmap

I want to be able to save an image as text in a xml file and I can't manage to find a efficient way to do it !

So far I tried :

```
QByteArray ImageAsByteArray;
QBuffer ImageBuffer(&ImageAsByteArray);
ImageBuffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
rImage.save(&ImageBuffer, "PNG"); 

return QString(ImageAsByteArray.toBase64());
```

Despite the fact it's working, the result is a file that is huge ! I tried adding some QCompress in there but without much success... Actually the QCompress doesn't seem to compress anything...

I think I'm doing it the wrong way, but could someone enlight my path please ?

Comment: how can you tell qCompress doesn't compress anything ? Are you checking the resulting text size or the binary size of the image ? Besides, do you need PNG images, or could you use JPEG with high compression ratio ?

Comment: Hi Jérôme :) Well, I've actually called QCompress on ImageAsByteArray, creating therefore another bytearray, and the size's difference between the two vars is really small... Actually, I would need jpg and png... This snippet is just for test purpose !

Comment: What is "huge"?  100x100 pixels x3 bytes per pixel raw data is already 30kB, if you compress that a bit by using PNG or JPEG you could reduce it to 5kB or maybe 10kB (depending on the image of course), and if you use base64 encoding over that it becomes 8kB-15kB.  So yeah, that's a long string for only 100x100 pixels, but really to be expected.

Comment: By the way, you can convert the image to 1 bit pixels to reduce the size by almost 95%, but it depends on your use.  See http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qimage.html#convertToFormat .

Comment: Actually, for an image of 170 ko (jpg) loaded from a file, after reading it, compress, save at string, I got nearly 1 Mo of text... So as you can guess, it's annoying... I'm not talking about images the user would import that are fresh out of the camera... I guess I'll simply resize them all before saving...

Comment: Encoding binary into base64 should increase the size of 33%. But then, how is this string encoded into the file ? UTF-8 ? UTF-16 ? What is the size of the QString you get after the conversion to base64 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you loading the image file to QImage and then getting the bytes from that QImage? If yes, then you are base64 encoding the raw image. In that case it really doesn't matter at all how much the original image file is compressed.

You should read the original image file (png or jpg) as a binary stream and base64 encode that stream. Example:

```
QFile* file = new QFile("Image001.jpg");
file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QByteArray image = file->readAll();
int originalSize = image.length();

QString encoded = QString(image.toBase64());
int encodedSize = encoded.size();
```

My test image's `originalSize` is 1028558 bytes, and `encodedSize` is 1371412 bytes, which is 33% more than the originalSize (see Jérôme's comment to your question).

Comment: It works this way but, at some point I'll need a QPixmap to display this image... And when I save it after using it, its size is increased by a 10 factor... It's annoying because for some reasons (resize purpose for example) I want to have a QImage or a QPixmap, but each time, the size of the image is dramatically increased as soon as it's been one of those objects... Any ideas ?

Comment: If you have a QPixmap, save it first to a QByteArray (see http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qpixmap.html#save-2 ), for example in JPG format. Now you can save that byte array (containing the image data in compressed format) to the disk.

Comment: That's what I did, but if I need to resize the image, I have to first make it a QPixmal (or QImage), resize it, then get it as a QByteArray, but the weight is much bigger ! As soon as I pass the image into a QPixmap, I can't get it back to QByteArray with a correct weight...

Comment: Update : In fact, I realised that, when using "MyImage.save(&PNGImageBuffer, "PNG")" with a source JPG format, the image's size is dramatically increased... On the other side, when I open a PNG image then use "MyImage.save(&JPGImageBuffer, "JPG")", I got no increase in size... Exemple, after opening a 16 ko Jpg file, once I saved it with PNG format, the size was 152ko... That's why I was confused... I hope I finally got it right....